# In Sorry!, do you have to move past safety zone or forfeit turn?

Tags: sorry

In Sorry, if you are 7 spaces away from your Home and you draw a 12 (and your other pawns are in Start or Home), do you have to move past your safety zone like you're going around the board a second time or do you forfeit your turn?

Answer (score 9):

You forfeit your turn.

From the [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/documents/dad288711c4311ddbd0b0800200c9a66/46ACC68319B9F36910005BB69E429D41.pdf) (3 separate places):

> - You must bring all four of your pawns into HOME by 
>     exact count!
> - If at any time you cannot move, you forfeit your turn.
> - When moving along 
>     the outside track, you may not move your pawn 
>     forward beyond your own SAFETY ZONE entry.

Also a note under the rules for the 11 card:

> - You may forfeit your move if you do not wish to change 
>     places and it is impossible to go forward 11 spaces.